# Is this possible to achieve by creating a table in HTML AND CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I do know a bit of javascript and Jquery, but i prefer to use HTML and Css.

[This image was created in Word, if I can replicate this in HTML and Css that would be great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5nlA.jpg)

Comment: Both flex and bootstrap will achieve this layout easily.

Comment: Can you give me the basics, or send a link with a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Great tut on flexbox: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bootstrap solution - divide the page into thirds and then for the left and right columns add vertically stacked divs that span the full width of these columns.

```css
.columnWrapper{border: solid 1px #333;text-align:center;margin:0}
#leftColumn {
  border-right: solid 1px #333;
  padding:0
}

#rightColumn {
  border-left: solid 1px #333;
  padding:0
}


#leftColumn div,
#rightColumn div{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
  line-height:3em
}

#leftColumn div:last-of-type,
#rightColumn div:last-of-type {
 border-bottom-width: 0
}

#middleColumn {
 line-height: 9em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
   <div class="columnWrapper clearfix">
      <div class="col-xs-4" id="leftColumn">
       <div>TEXT</div>
       <div>TEXT</div>
       <div>TEXT</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4" id="middleColumn">
       <div>PHOTO</div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4" id="rightColumn">
       <div>TEXT</div>
       <div>TEXT</div>
       <div>TEXT</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```